# Unable to use loadTokenizer of Tensorflow JS

Tags: javascript, npm, package, tokenize, tensorflow.js

This is my first time dealing with Tensorflow.js things. I was trying to tokenize my sentence in Javascript with Universal Sentence Encoder. [Github Reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/universal-sentence-encoder)

```
$ npm install @tensorflow/tfjs @tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder
```

With this command, I installed a package-lock.json and I moved it to the same directory with my index.html file. The directory as shown below.

```
/*
  Folder
    |_index.html
    |_package-lock.json
    |_index.js
    |_index.css
*/
```

index.html

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder"></script>   
  <script src="index.js" defer></script> 
</head>
```

index.js

```
function tokenizePad(text){
    text = use.loadTokenizer().then(tokenizer => {
        tokenizer.encode(text); 
    });
    return text;
}

text = "I enjoy my holiday very much."
var tokenized = tokenizePad(text); //error
```

Error message in the console as shown below

```
Uncaught TypeError: use.loadTokenizer is not a function
```

Any fix for the problem? Or is there any other alternative solution to achieve the same thing? I would like to convert my string into something like this  [341, 4125, 8, 140, 31, 19, 54, ......] as described in the Github Reference link

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this. I ended up with the following:

```
use.load().then(useObj => {
    model = useObj.model;
    tokenizer = useObj.tokenizer;

    text = "I enjoy my holiday very much."
    var tokenized = tokenizer.encode(text); 

    console.log(tokenized); //[7933, 2222, 0, 109, 7933, 2222, 0, 154, 2174, 48, 7933, 2222, 0, 1272, 7933, 2222, 0, 645, 336, 944, 7933, 2222, 0, 5568, 7933, 2222, 0, 47, 1788, 6]
});
```

This is on character level though. Let me know if you found a way to get the word based encoding.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your sharing too

Answer (score 0):

This is more robust and elegant. First import it as such:

```
import * as use from '@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder';
```

Then use it with `use`:

```
// Load the model.
use.load().then(model => {
  // Embed an array of sentences.
  const sentences = [
    'Hello.',
    'How are you?'
  ];
  model.embed(sentences).then(embeddings => {
    // `embeddings` is a 2D tensor consisting of the 512-dimensional embeddings for each sentence.
    // So in this example `embeddings` has the shape [2, 512].
    embeddings.print(true /* verbose */);
  });
});
```